# How and where to save images uploaded by user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, razor, web-deployment

I am working on an issue. The issue is: I have to create an image slider using ASP.Net MVC. I have done the necessary coding for that and it is running fine when I am using the images which are saved in my application folder (deployed to QA environment, works fine there too).

Now, the next requirement is that I want to give control to other users (from within the organization itself) to control the images (add/delete some images from the shared folder, from which the application can access the images for slider).

For this purpose, I have written a script that updates a folder on QA environment (say, "C:\MyApp\Images") as per changes in the shared folder. I was earlier thinking that I would ask my application to read images from that particular folder ("C:\MyApp\Images") on the QA environment when the application runs there. But, now I got to know that `img` tag will try to read it from client's machine, if I give path like "C:\MyApp\Images" as its `src` attribute. Also, doing this will give rise to a security vulnerability.

So, how to handle this? Where to save those images?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is marked as opinion-based question. I agree that there can be more than one solutions to this, but I am expecting someone to come up with at least one appropriate solution.
 
Hence, please remove the hold on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relational path:

```
<img src="/images/image.png" />
```

This will look for the image.png file in the images folder within your application's root.

Comment: I can do this. But, then the main Q remains unaswered...how can I store the images there on the fly?

Comment: If you've written a script to update some arbitrary folder when users change images in your application, it shouldn't be difficult to set that arbitrary folder to be one on the server that the application is running on. If you're publishing to different environments, considering storing that folder path in a config file and transforming based on some configuration variable.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am doing. But, the problem that I was facing is that, because I am using `Octopus Deploy` for the deployment, it every time creates a new folder (with random name) on the server from which the website runs. So, in my script, I won't be able to give the path to the folder where the solution would be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Always save the images to your own system. It would reduce the vulnerability that you're talking about, secondly it reduces chances of ImageNotFound error too.

You should try to save the images on the Server, and let the users use the image when they're surfing your application. You can use Guid to name the images seperately. This would minimize the error of similar named image too and each user would have his own uploaded image.

The control would be simple, you would use a loop to show the images, and each image would have a simple Delete button. Which would lead to a new URL such as `delete_image?image_id=someId`. This would be enough.

But, don't save the images on the Client's machine, the most general issue in this would be, that the user would delete images when he wants. The record would be available on your machine, and this **could** cause a NullPointerException.

Second thing, `img` tag would only try to read it from client's machine, if it is **cached**. Otherwise how can HTML read and render the elements from the Client machine. It doesn't do so! Only does, when there is caching available and the image file is present for use.

Last thing, use the Operator `~/` to give path for the image. For example, if you're running a website, which has a Path as,

> C:\Users[username]\Documents\My Websites[website_name]\Images

Then you  can use this code to get the images, from the Images folder easily without hard coding it.

```
<img src="~/images/image.png" alt="photo" />
```

This would be pretty handy, as the Server-side language would try to look for the image file in the File System.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am looking for something with which users would be able to add images too (not simply choosing the ones from specific set of images which are stored on Server). In other words, users should be able to save more images to the server as well.

Comment: They can upload the images to the very same folder too. There is no shyness while letting the user upload the images to that folder. They won't be fighting! :)